# Can Windows 10 Event Logs be used to determine which programs were installed on a machine and when?

Tags: linux, windows-10, bash, debian, forensics

I found [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288077/3570) for the package manager logs Debian which can show you when and in what order packages have been installed or updated from Bash.  Is there any sort of equivalent to this in Windows 10, such as using the event logs to find out which programs were installed and when?

Comment: well, there's the list of add/remove programs that all have an install date. You're probably looking for something more comprehensive than this though

Comment: @Blaine well yeah...but I figure there's enough information in some of those Windows log statements; ya just have to know what Event ID to look up.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to ask for the Event IDs for installs so that you can filter the Event Logs to get such a list? I think that would make the question a little more clear.

Comment: @music2myear done.